# @ (at) symbols preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex

Is the "@" symbol sometimes used to surround a PHP regular expression? I'm working with a code base and found this function call:

```
$content = preg_replace("@(</?[^>]*>)+@", "", $content);
```

I believe it's removing all XML tags from the string but I'm not sure what the "@" symbol in there means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be used to wrap the expression. The original author most likely does this because some (or several) expressions contain the "more traditional" `/` delimiter. By using `@`, you can now use `/` without the need to escape it.

You could use:

- `/pattern/flags` (traditional)
- `@pattern@flags`
- `$pattern$flags`
- etc.

Comment: @Henning: That may be the "black sheep". Given the presence of HTML characters, it's likely that other expressions (also found within that file) have some form of `/` in it (e.g. looking for `</a>`). But you're correct, no `/` in _that_ expression.

Comment: Typo on my part, it was meant to be a slash and not a backslash. So you're probably correct in why they chose the @ character.

Answer (score 2):

The manual calls them the [PCRE "**delimiters**"](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Any ASCII symbol (non-alphanumeric) can be used (except the null byte).

Common alternatives to `/` are `~` and `#`. But `@` is just as valid.

PCRE also allows matching braces like `(...)` or `<...>` for the regular expression.

Comment: Not any ASCII character - only non-alnums, and the backslash is invalid, too.

Comment: A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nearly any punctuation character as a delimiter in PHP regular expressions. [See the docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Usually, the `/` is the first choice (and I would have suggested its use here), but if your regex contains slashes, a different character can be useful.

Mostly, I've seen `%...%`, `~...~` and `#...#`, but `@...@` is OK, too.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes. The specific symbol used isn't important; it should generally be something that doesn't appear within the pattern. For example, these are all equivalent:

```
<?php
    preg_replace("@(<\?[^>]*>)+@", "", $content);
    preg_replace("/(<\?[^>]*>)+/", "", $content);
    preg_replace("!(<\?[^>]*>)+!", "", $content);  
?>
```

The reason the symbol is necessary is because modifiers may be added after the expression. For example, to search case insensitive, you could use:

```
<?php
   preg_replace("@(<\?[^>]*>)+@i", "", $content);
?>
```